# English equivalent of the French custom "l'apéro"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, translation, french

In France, when gathered with friends, it is customary to drink beers or other light alcohol around 7pm, and this time is called *apéritif* (or *apéro*). Does this custom have an English (UK and/or US) equivalent? How would you say "on se verra à l'apéro"?

Comment: I read about the english word 'aperitif' but I understand it refers to the drink rather than the time / occasion.

Comment: There is a cultural difference in that 7 PM is around the time where most British and American people would be having _dinner_ (or supper). As such, there really isn’t a word to describe having light drinks around 7 PM, because you generally don’t meet up with people to do that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Great, thanks, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's more drinks before a meal, you can get one before lunch as well.

Comment: The word "aperitif" is used in English, but it does essentially refer to the drink itself. But if you call it "pre-dinner drink and nibbles" people will get the idea.

Comment: P.S. Interesting cultural difference: in French people tend to say "prendre l'apéro" with the definite article, in English you would probably more naturally say "have *a* pre-dinner drink (and nibbles)" with the indefinite article. Sometimes social commentary lies simply in the use of articles :)

Comment: The correct answer should be "pregame" - at least in America, that's what people say.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term *[cocktail hour](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cocktail+hour?r=66)* has been used in the US to mean

> the interval before the evening meal during which cocktails and other alcoholic beverages are often served

However, this is not limited to beer and light alcoholic beverages, but may include wine or strong spirits as well.

Comment: Is _cockatil hour_ formal or informal ? Would you say "come swing by for the cocktail hour" ?

Comment: Cocktail hour is somewhat formal. Many people would say *Swing by for cocktails* which carries with it he suggestion of timing (in the evening before dinner).

Answer (score 6):

Some places have "happy hour", where a bar serves slightly cheaper drinks in the early evening.

There's a whole load of vernacular expressions for going to the pub and having a drink, but they're not really associated with a time: "go for a pint", "swift half", etc.

Answer (score 2):

The apéro is a French phenomenon, a particularly pleasant one --especially when combined with ti' punch-- but as already pointed out there is no equivalent term for it in English because the custom itself does not exist.

The closest translation I can think of is [*tea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_%28meal%29). In Britain and the British world, you can meet for tea which means something to eat and, well, tea. The exact time varies from place to place and according to social background (see the link above) but *come over for tea* will be understood in the British world as *come over this afternoon for a light snack and a drink*.

As a native English speaker living in the south of France I must stress again that this does *not* have the same connotations as the French apéro. For example, alcohol may well be absent if you meet for tea while it most certainly will be present if you meet for apéro. Still *tea* is the closest you'll find in English.

---

EDIT: *Coctail hour* is indeed closer despite this being the accepted answer.

Comment: Does that mean it is common **not** to drink tea when "coming over for tea"? And I held the British in such a great esteem...

Comment: @Aeronth not really, the offering and drinking of tea is a very important part of British culture, tea will be on offer in almost any social context. If you invite someone over for tea, actual leaf infusions are not mandatory but they are customary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest equivalent has another French word:

[Hors d'oeuvre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hors_d%27oeuvre) which is also called Appetizers

It is more food related, but is close to your situation as in

> Can we meet for appetizers?

That said, I (Danish) would certainly understand what you meant if you asked me to join you for an apéritif

Comment: *apéritif* is certainly also used in Britain, but (in my experience) it would more usually be used for a drink before a meal *at the same location*; i.e. you've already arranged to have a meal together (in a home, pub, restaurant, etc.) and, when you meet, you ask if guests want an apéritif.

Answer (score -1):

In spite of what is being said, I believe that "Happy Hour," traditionally after high tea (4pm) and before the evening meal (supper/dinner around 7 or 8pm) is a common tradition where not only are drinks cheaper in order for the establishment to attract a larger clientele in this off-hour, but often nibbles or little bite-sized food and appropriately small plates are provided gratis.  Both provided by private or commercial establishments to boost their off-hours with the hopes of providing the local cafe or hotel restaurant with an evening's crowd and happy returning customers.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, so only direct answers to the original question should be posted in the Your Answer box. This contribution would have been better as a comment (like this one), which you will be able to leave when you have gained additional site reputation. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a further introduction.